# Google Actions - can I trigger an action on one device by chaning another device status?

Tags: actions-on-google

Im new to Google actions and really appreciate any help.
Here is a scenario just to make my question clear:
I have 3 smart light switches in 1 room. I would like to turn one of the switches on  (physically) and have google home to turn on the remaining 2 switches for me.
So i understand that i can write a command to turn the 2 light switches on, i dont see any problems here. The tricky part is - how do i create a trigger from physically changing the status of the first switch. Is that even possible?
If yes where should i start? im not sure from which end to approach it. Im new to this and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform does not provide a way to trigger any actions on a device state change, so your use case would not be possible using the Google Assistant.

Comment: thank u. i looked into Kasa platform. I think they provide this option through UI. Gonna give it a try